# how to get my Material-UI table to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've looked on here, and people have recommended that I store a boolean in state to conditionally render it later on, however, when showTable is set to true, everything disappears.

Here is my code that is being rendered into app

**compoundInterest.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
import MonetizationOnIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MonetizationOn';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import DataTable from './DataTable';


function createData(key, term, balance) {
  return { key, term, balance };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: '25ch',
    },
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));




function CompoundInterest() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ interestRate: 0.01, Balance: 0, Year: 1, Compounds: 1, currency: '£', showComponent: false });
  const [show, setShow] = useState({ showTable: false });

  let rows = [];

  const handleChange = (event) => {

    setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const classes = useStyles();


  const calculate = (e) => {
    let balance = state.Balance;
    let rate = state.interestRate;
    let time = state.Year;
    let Compounds = state.Compounds;
    let A = 0;
    rows = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= Compounds * time; i++) {
      A = (balance * (1 + (rate / 100)));
      balance = A;
      rows.push(createData(`${i}`, `Compound term ${i}`, Math.round(balance * 100) / 100));
    }

    setShow({ showTable: true });
  };


  return (
    <div >

      <form className={classes.root} noValidate>

        <FormControl component="fieldset">
          <FormLabel component="legend">Currency</FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup aria-label="currency" name="currency" value={state.currency} onChange={handleChange} row>
            <FormControlLabel value="£" control={<Radio />} label="£" />
            <FormControlLabel value="$" control={<Radio />} label="$" />
            <FormControlLabel value="€" control={<Radio />} label="€" />
            <FormControlLabel value="¥" control={<Radio />} label="¥" />
          </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>

        <InputLabel>Amount
          <Input id="standard-basic-amount"
            name='Balance'
            onChange={handleChange}
            type="number"
            value={state.Balance}
            startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start">{state.currency}</InputAdornment>} />
        </InputLabel>

        <InputLabel>Interest rate
          <Input id="standard-basic-rate"
            name='interestRate'
            onChange={handleChange}
            type="number"
            value={state.interestRate}
            endAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start">%</InputAdornment>} />
        </InputLabel>

        <InputLabel>Year(s)
          <Input id="standard-basic-time"
            name='Year'
            onChange={handleChange}
            type="number"
            value={state.Year}
          />
        </InputLabel>

        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Compound Term</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            value={state.Compounds}
            label="Compound term"
            onChange={handleChange}
            name="Compounds"
          >
            <MenuItem value={1}>Yearly</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={2}>Bi-annually</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={4}>Quaterly</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={12}>Monthly</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={52}>Weekly</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={365}>Daily</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>


        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.button}
          startIcon={<MonetizationOnIcon />}
          onClick={calculate}
        >
        </Button>

      </form>

      <div> {show.showTable ? <DataTable rows={rows} /> : null}</div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default CompoundInterest;
```

Here is my **Datatable.js** component which has the actual material-ui table

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell, { tableCellClasses } from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';

const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)(({ theme }) => ({
    [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
        color: theme.palette.common.white,
    },
    [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
        fontSize: 14,
    },
}));

const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme }) => ({
    '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
    },
    // hide last border
    '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': {
        border: 0,
    },
}));




export default function DataTable() {
    return (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table sx={{ minWidth: 700 }} aria-label="customized table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <StyledTableCell>Compund Term</StyledTableCell>
                        <StyledTableCell align="right">Balance</StyledTableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {this.props.rows.map((row) => (
                        <StyledTableRow key={row.key}>
                            <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                {row.term}
                            </StyledTableCell>
                            <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.balance}</StyledTableCell>

                        </StyledTableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
```

Comment: Maybe you can try: const [show, setShow] = useState(false); and then setShow(true); after you can ask: <div> {show ? <DataTable rows={rows} /> : null}</div>

Comment: @IvanZ. thanks for responding, but same thing, everything just disappears when I click the button.